# Latest version of Skype app from their website doesn't work

Tags: skype

I’m using Ubuntu 18.04, and the latest version of Skype from their website. It installs fine, but whenever I try and make a call I get an error saying “oops, something went wrong”.

I know it is not a problem with my account as the web client works fine.

Comment: Yes I did. That was what I tried first. I’ll try again this morning. Is there a way to remove the old version completely (configs etc.) so I can start from scratch?

Comment: `sudo snap remove --purge skype` removes it, but in my experience reinstalling a snap package doesn't work either. If you wait for an update to a snap package that doesn't work 2 things can happen. 1. The problem is solved by an update. 2. The snap package's maintainer removes the app from the Snap Store.

Comment: I'm also getting the same problem when trying to access their web skype from the web client. It's literally been going on for a week now. It forces a restart, then within a few seconds it crashes and demands a restart.